# Adding to Firestore collection

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add to the "receipts" collection a document with a unique "id: and for this document the data:" id "," from "," value "and" image ". Firebase
!!important !!code in Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add a document to a specific collection with a unique ID, then you should use the [DocumentReference#set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#set(java.lang.Object)) method which:

> Writes to the document referred to by this DocumentReference.

In code, it should look like this:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val receiptsRef = db.collection("receipts")
val docId = receiptsRef.document().id
val receipt = mapOf(
    "id" to docId,
    "from" to "Name",
    "value" to "The value of the receipt",
    "image" to "URL of the image"
)
receiptsRef.document(docId).set(receipt)
```

You can also use [addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener listener)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)), to see if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is no such command in Firebase. Therefore, you should take the data you entered and search it in Firestore. You can perform the operation according to the condition.